How to align Text on y-axis in DropdownButtonFormField in Flutter
I'm trying to align the text on the y-axis in the dropdown menu using Flutter's DropdownButtonFormField while using a PrefixIcon but no solutions are working well for me. If I remove the PrefixIcon, the Text is centered well.
I tried removing the PrefixIcon and used a Row widget with the image and text but the icon then repeats on the dropdown which I don't want.
This is my first time asking a question so the screenshot is shown via a link: Misaligned Text in DropdownButtonFormField
This is my code:
DropdownButtonFormField(
                  focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                  value: _selectedMasjid,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  items: _masjidList.map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: e,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text( //THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO ALIGN
                        e, 
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
                      
                  .toList(),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedMasjid = val as String;
                    });
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple.shade100, width: 1.5),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple.shade400, width: 1.5),
                    ),
                    prefixIcon: //THIS IS THE PREFIX ICON
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/mosque.png', 
                      height: 2,
                    ),
                  ),
                  dropdownColor: Colors.deepPurple.shade200,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_drop_down_rounded,
                    color: Colors.deepPurple.shade300,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                ),



